# how to fadein child element of class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my data and now I want to fadein elements of class data one by one

```
.data
 {
    width: 74%;
    background: red;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 13%;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
}
    <div class="data">data A1
    </div>
    <div class="data"> data B1
    </div>
    <div class="data"> data C1
    </div>
    <div class="data"> data D1
    </div>
```

I tried `$(".data")[0].fadeIn(2000)` as well as `$(".data")[0].delay(200).fadeIn(2000)`
both gives error when I use index but works fine when removed index but then all child fadeIn at same time.

Comment: The documentation is so very helpful. You need to pass an options object with either `queue` or `done` callbacks: http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Comment: please see my answer for the correct solution to guarantee each div is shown _one by one_. Any solutions based upon `setTimeout` cannot guarantee the order of display.

Answer (score 0):

You're dereferencing the array you get when you do `$(".data")[0]` and end up with the underlying DOM node which you can't use a jQuery method on. Instead of using `$(".data")[0]`, use `$(".data:first")`, `$(".data:eq(0)")`, `$(".data").eq(0)`, or `$(".data").first()`

Answer (score 0):

What your doing gets the single DOM element, rather than getting a jquery representation of that element, in your case you could do soemthing like:

```
var ele = $(".data")[0]
$(ele).fadeIn(2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target certain elements of the same class in jQuery using `.eq()`

`$(".data").eq(2).fadeIn(1000);`

You could create a `for` loop to iterate through each element with the class name and use a `setTimeout` to give a delay before fading in.

More examples at:
https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each()` and `setTimeout()`

```js
$('.data').each(function(i){
  var ThisIt = $(this);
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.data').fadeOut(200);
    ThisIt.fadeIn(200);
  } , 3000 * i);
});
```

```css
.data
 {
    width: 74%;
    background: red;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 13%;
    display : flex;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="data">data A1
</div>
<div class="data"> data B1
</div>
<div class="data"> data C1
</div>
<div class="data"> data D1
</div>
```

**OR :** You can use something like `delay()` , `.queue()` and `addClass()`

```js
$('.data').each(function(i){
  var ThisIt = $(this);
  ThisIt.delay(2000 * i).queue(function(){
    $(this).addClass('visible');
  });
});
```

```css
.data
 {
    width: 74%;
    background: red;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 13%;
    display : flex;
    text-align: center;
    visibility : hidden;
    opacity : 0;
}
.visible{
  visibility : visible;
  opacity : 1;
  transition-duration : 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="data">data A1
</div>
<div class="data"> data B1
</div>
<div class="data"> data C1
</div>
<div class="data"> data D1
</div>
```

> **Note:** this code just to start with .. you can play around to make it
>   infinite loop

Comment: This does not guarantee the images will be displayed _**one after another**_, only that they will each be displayed after a certain time period.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I got your point .. but I said *this code just to start with* maybe he need to remove `setTimeout()` maybe use the index in the `fadeIn(3000 * index)` actually there are more and more of things he can do with this code and with another answers as well . Thank you for your comment :-)

Comment: my point was simply that you did not answer the question that was asked. A catchall "but you can edit this to work" is sort of not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need.

(is not the best code but should work)

```js
var a=0;
$(".data").each(function(){
 a++;
 $(this).fadeIn(1000*a);
});
```

```css
.data
 {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    height: 20px;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data">data A1
    </div>
    <div class="data"> data B1
    </div>
    <div class="data"> data C1
    </div>
    <div class="data"> data D1
    </div>
```

Comment: no need to use `a++` if you need to start with index 0 you can just pass index in `.each(function(index))` .. it'll be right if you need to start with random index .. by the way I like this effect .. but unfortunate its not the same css the OP provide .. no one know may be this is the effect he want .. Good Luck :-)

Comment: This does not guarantee the images will be displayed _**one after another**_, only that they will each be displayed after a certain time period.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use JS then a CSS approach is using `@keyframes` you just need to delay the start time of the element using `animate-delay` and adding the required classes to the elements. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9dfomt4/8/) Hope this helps.

```css
.fadeIn{
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}
.animated1{
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.animated2{
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-delay: 2s;
}
.animated3{
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-delay: 4s;
}
.animated4{
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-delay: 6s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn
{
  0%
  {
    opacity:0;
    }
   to{
     opacity:1;
     }
}
.fadeIn{
  animation-name:fadeIn;
  }
```

```html
<div class="data fadeIn animated1">data A1
    </div>
    <div class="data fadeIn animated2"> data B1
    </div>
    <div class="data fadeIn animated3"> data C1
    </div>
    <div class="data fadeIn animated4"> data D1
    </div>
```

Comment: This does not guarantee the images will be displayed _**one after another**_, only that they will each be displayed after a certain time period.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursion to animate the 1st element of the collection. Whenever the current [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) animation ends, call the function with the collection, but with the 1st item removed by [`.slice()`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```js
function fadeIn($els) {
  $els.eq(0).fadeIn(1000, function() {
    fadeIn($els.slice(1));
  });
}

fadeIn($('.data'))
```

```css
.data {
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data">data A1
</div>
<div class="data"> data B1
</div>
<div class="data"> data C1
</div>
<div class="data"> data D1
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the other answers, this answer guarantees that each will follow the previous. The other answers cannot guarantee that using timeouts.

This is a function that correctly uses the callback to recurse through each `<div>` to display them ***one after another*** as the question requests.

I've made two modifications to your base CSS. I set the `background-color` to white (for easier reading) and the set the `display` to `none` so the animation will be visible.

```js
let collection = $('.data');
(function doIt(index) {
  $(collection[index])
  .fadeIn(2000, () => {
      if (index++ < collection.length) doIt(index);
    });
})(0);
```

```css
.data {
  width: 74%;
  background: white;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 13%;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data">data A1
</div>
<div class="data"> data B1
</div>
<div class="data"> data C1
</div>
<div class="data"> data D1
</div>
```